# Is there a concept that describes the relationship between A and B where one is a subset of the other?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I feel like there must be a name for this.

What is the relationship between A and B called if (A⊆B or A⊋B) is true?

Comment: $A$ *is included into* $B$ or $A$ *is a subset of* $B$ ... See [Subset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) : "The relationship of one set being a subset of another is called inclusion or sometimes containment."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Nick R's simplification, whenever two elements of a poset satisfy "$A\leq B$ or $B\leq A$" we say that $A$ and $B$ are **comparable**. Here, we can consider $A$ and $B$ to be comparable as elements of some implicit poset, for instance $2^{A\cup B}$.

Answer (score 0):

You say, "$A$ is a a subset of $B$" or "$B$ is a superset of $A$'' [less common].

Comment: Ok. I want to say that A and B are x, where x would mean that (A⊆B or A⊋B) is true. Maybe this is a question about english not mathematics :)

Comment: @Eric Stucky Ok. Are you saying that the 'A and B are X' formulation is rarely used? The question is influenced by thinking about relations between nodes in a tree, so maybe I shouldn't be relating this to sets?

Comment: @Skúli: Actually I misunderstood; I thought it was "$A\subseteq B$ or $A\not\supseteq B$". [Also no, that was not what I was saying.]